# Missing internal rate on Exact Online employment

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql

When you have an employment in Exact Online, you can have an internal rate. The APIs also list it as the column `InternalRate` in `ExactOnlineREST..EmploymentSalaries`.

But in the tab Employment of an Employee it is not visible.

How can I enter a value for internal rate?

Answer (score 0):

The internal rate is only available when you don't have all features enabled. For instance, when you have a Projects subscription, the field will appear as shown below:
[image: Sample internal rate on employment]

But when you have all features available through an App Center Subscription, including Payrolling, you will miss the field.

I didn't need to create an additional trial subscription. I was told that you can switch the subscription type per division, even with the App Center subscription:

- Go to Companies (top left)
- Choose 'show all'.
- Choose company.
- Click on 'Change' with 'Company Types'.
- Select type:

[image: Change type to get internal rates visible]